# Getting specific wavelength bands from TIFF UAV image

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff

I use UAV .tif images gathered from a sensor that uses: 550nm, 660nm, 735nm, 790nm. I need however, to do some calculations with the channels: 531nm and 570nm. Is it possible to get the channels I want from that image?

These sensors have a bandwidth for each band, so 550 +/- something, etc. And the idea is to isolate the bands 531, 570 somehow.

I am going to code in Python.

Comment: Can you wrok with GDAL, or QGIS? Please, edit the question to include any program, that you have access to, to perform the task.

Comment: Ok, I updated the first post. So I search for GDAL code, if I understood correctly...

Comment: For what operation am I looking for in GDAL?

Comment: With [gdal_calc.py](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html) you can make raster bands algebra, if that is what you need.

Comment: Here: gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --A_band=1 -B input.tif --B_band=2 --outfile=result.tif --calc="(A+B)/2" --calc="B*logical_and(A>100,A<150)" the 100 and 150 stand for nm (wavelength) ?

Comment: You say that you have bands for 550, 660, 735 and 790 nm, but you want to operate with 531 and 570 nm. I don't understand what are you trying to do. You don't have bands for 531 and 570 nm. How do you want to operate them?

Comment: Yes, but these sensors have a bandwidth for each band, so 550 +/- something, etc... And the idea is to isolate the bands 531, 570 somehow..! I am not specialized on this that is why I am asking here..

Comment: Sometimes we have a formula to estimate the value of the digital level of an absent band based on the values in the present bands, for example estimating the value of red based on the values of blue, green and infrared. Do you have any formula to estimate the values in the missing bands?

Comment: No I do not have a formula to estimate the missing bands. What tools I need for this calculation? Can I achieve that with python code?